# How to render a full html in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, render

I have an HTML file with meta tags,header,body,forms coming from server in a string
Now my doubt is how to open that full fledged html in reactjs since we already have a master index.html in reactjs. When I tried to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` it is giving a blank page.

Comment: did you check this: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: Yes I am using the dangerouslySetInnerHTML but my problem is a bit different. We already have our index.html file but from the server I am getting one payment gateway html which is something like this

<html><head>....</head><body>....</body></html> . Now when I render this with dangerouslySetInnerHTML in a div its giving blank.

Comment: You can render it in iframe but it's ugly

Comment: Better if the server sends only json and client renders jsx.or you can turn your spa into ssr

Comment: do you have any errors in the console? you could select only the contents of the body of that html file and render that inside dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: My Problem is the content is coming from the mastercard payment gateway (Otp page) and I need to render it as it is. Because there are hidden calls to it.

Comment: Another option is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser. It's pretty cool library to parse html to react components but it's 70kb

Comment: So maybe iframe is best solution if it's embedded kind of content.

Comment: how to use the iframe with the html from server. Can you guide me I am a bit new in React.

The Html coming from server is something like this

`
<html>
<head>
<title>.....</title>
<meta ...><style 
</style>
</head>
<body onload="...">
<form name="XXX" method="POST" action="XXX" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input type="hidden" name="QQQ" value="XXX"><input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="A"><input type="hidden" name="MD" value="XXX"><noscript><div id="msg"><div id="submitButton"><input type="submit" value="C" class="button"></div></div></noscript>

</form>
</body>
</html>
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you can do it in various ways.
As much as I hate iframes it could be the right solution for you.

**NOTE**: this solution has nothing to do with React

```
import React from "react";

const html = `<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>div{
    background: red;
    color: white;
  }</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello iframe</div>
</body>
</html>`

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <iframe srcDoc={html} title="my-iframe"></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```

see live example: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-moser-mk28l)

please read about iframes in MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for more config

more reading about polyfill to `srcDoc`: [here](https://medium.com/the-thinkmill/how-to-safely-inject-html-in-react-using-an-iframe-adc775d458bc)

Comment: Thanks it worked like charm .. but one more question how to read the response which the form in iframe is submitting. Right now it shows the jSON response in the page when the form is submitted. This is not expected. My main page should get some listener to get the event.

The iFrame looks like this

<body onload="return window.document.echoForm.submit()">

<form ....></form>

Comment: You can use `postMessage` event to pass data between the `iframe` and the main page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I suggest you contact the support of this 3rd party solution you are using maybe they can help you. it seems like there's a gap here of how to implement it(on your side).

Comment: Finally everything worked. I implemented a listener API for the payment integration. Once the listener receives success response I close the iframe. Thanks all for supporting. The solution of opening the link in iframe worked and also implementing the listener.